# How is the separator from the explode command correct?

Tags: php

I have a string:

```js
$test = "{"Classes":"[94,134,114,48,112,113,90,133,89,128,132,115]","ControlClasses":"[]","SecureClasses":"[]","SecureControlClasses":"[]"}"
```

I want this string split with the PHP-command `explode`.
As separator I want to use `","` (All three characters!).
How is the command correct?

```
$result = explode("","", $test);   // error
```

Comment: Wouldn't `json_decode()` be a better way of decoding it?

Comment: You mean like this? - `$result = explode("\",\"", $test);`

Comment: First, just to be sure, do you know that string is JSON? And if so _why_ do you need to access it as a string rather than in the standard way to process JSON with PHP?

Comment: Second, you're getting syntax errors because you have unescaped double quotes inside double quotes, both in the example string and the code sample. You need to use single quotes or escape the quote with `\\`. But even though that may answer your question, it's actually somewhat beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//First things first
//do
$test = "{\"Classes\":\"[94,134,114,48,112,113,90,133,89,128,132,115]\",\"ControlClasses\":\"[]\",\"SecureClasses\":\"[]\",\"SecureControlClasses\":\"[]\"}";
//or
$test = '{"Classes":"[94,134,114,48,112,113,90,133,89,128,132,115]","ControlClasses":"[]","SecureClasses":"[]","SecureControlClasses":"[]"}';
//Then use JSON to get strings:
$result = json_decode($test, true); // Array("Classes" => "[94,134,114,48,112,113,90,133,89,128,132,115]", "ControlClasses" => "[]", "SecureClasses" => "[]", "SecureControlClasses" => "[]")
$classes = $result['Classes']; // "[94,134,114,48,112,113,90,133,89,128,132,115]"
$controlClasses = $result['ControlClasses']; // "[]"
$secureClasses = $result['SecureClasses']; // "[]"
//Now you should remove brackets
$classes = substr($classes, 1, strlen($classes) - 1);
$controlClasses = substr($controlClasses, 1, strlen($controlClasses) - 1);
$secureClasses = substr($secureClasses, 1, strlen($secureClasses) - 1);
//And only this time your dream gonna come true (it is disgusting)
$classes = explode(',', $classes);
$controlClasses = explode(',', $controlClasses);
$secureClasses = explode(',', $secureClasses);
//Here we are
echo $classes[3]; // 48
```